# Get page name from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to know what page i'm on based on the URL.

When i use `$(location).attr('href')`i get a very long url like this:

```
http://localhost:8181/research/gadgets/ifr?container=default&mid=0&nocache=0&country=ALL&lang=ALL&view=default&nerwVersion=~project.version~&url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8181%2Fresearch%2Fnerw-gadgets%2FCompanyDetails%2FCompanyDetails.xml&oaaParent=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8181
```

The URL in the browser looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8181/research/?view=home
```

How do i get the view=home bit?

Comment: So you actually want to retrieve a query string?

Comment: you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:-

```
function getQuerystring(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
        return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }

    Usage getQuerystring("view");
```